# command line arguments to add two numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to add two numbers using command line arguments... This is as far as I found on this site about adding 2 numbers using command arguments

```
import sys
a=sys.argv[1:]
b=sys.argv[2:]
sumn=str(a+b)
print(" sum is",sumn)
```

Comment: remove the columns when subscripting the `sys.argv` array, and cats to int

Comment: Please take a look at your individual results! For example print out `sys.argv[1:]` to see what you are doing. You should really learn to understand the code you are copying from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to int and subscript direct values, not slices

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    try:
        a = int(sys.argv[1])
        b = int(sys.argv[2])
        print("sum = %d" % (a + b))
    except ValueError:
        print("failed to parse all arguments as integers.")
        exit(1)
else:
    print("Not enough numbers to add")
```

EDIT: Added error handling as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Maybe you add some code to handle a possible `ValueError` when the user enters a string that cannot be casted to an integer to make your answer complete.